# When does the constant of integration appear when applying the Leibniz Integral Rule to an indefinite integral?

Tags: integration

I came across the following example in some lecture notes:
\begin{align}
\int xe^{ax} \mathrm dx &= \int \frac \partial {\partial a} \left[e^{ax}\right]\mathrm dx\\
&= \frac \partial {\partial a}\int e^{ax} \mathrm dx\\
&= \frac\partial{\partial a}\left(\frac 1 a e^{ax}\right) + C\\
&= \frac{axe^{ax} - e^{ax}}{a^2} + C
\end{align}

I am confused about what happens in line 3; the constant of integration appears outside of the parenthesis, but should it not be on the inside since that is where the result of the antiderivative is? But, if it was on the inside of the parenthesis, then, presumably, the partial should be able to act on it, but, as seen in line 4, the constant of integration hangs around (the notes that I was looking at even specifically made a point that the derivative will not touch the constant of integration). Does this mean that the derivative is still part of the integral on the whole -- as in the antiderivative is not complete until the derivative is evaluated? If that was the case, then I would think it more proper if the constant appeared at line 4 rather than line 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant of integration comes from the fact that the result of an indefinite integral is not a single function, but a family of functions. In some ways, it isn't really an actual constant, it's just a notation. In other contexts (e.g. when solving partial differential equations) we can have situations where it's only constant *with respect to the variable of integration*, but it is actually a function of other variables or parameters.

So in this case, the $+C$ appears in line 3 because what we're really doing is trying to find functions whose derivative with respect to $x$ is $x e^{ax}$, and so when applying Leibniz's rule and getting to a point with $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int e^{ax} dx$, the "constant" of integration that appears is only necessarily constant *with respect to $x$*. It could be any arbitrary function of $a$, and so when you take the partial derivative with respect to $a$ it's *still* an arbitrary function of $a$. But because we don't really care about the details of that, we just write it as $+C$ to represent the idea that any function of the form written in the answer is a valid antiderivative.